# Click view работает не так как нужно, как исправить?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, view

Всем привет

```
    <ScrollView>
     <HorizontalScrollView>
      <TableLayout>
      </TableLayout> 
     </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
```

Есть вот такой код 
MainActivity

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
               ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
               ....
               tableRow.addView(img);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
}
```

Так же я переопределяю метод в Activity

```
   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float curX, curY;
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case ACTION_DOWN:
                    mx = event.getX();
                    my = event.getY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    curX = event.getX();
                    curY = event.getY();
                    vScroll.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                    hScroll.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                    mx = curX;
                    my = curY;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    curX = event.getX();
                    curY = event.getY();
                    vScroll.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                    hScroll.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
                    break;
            }
        return true;
    }
```

Так я реализовал вертикальный и горизонтальный скрол и все работает хорошо если элементы не вмещаются на экран то появляются скролы и могу листать и верх и вниз и в любом направлении.
Но тут появляется проблема, если я на ImageView вешаю событие клик,
gifImageView.setOnClickListener
то при скроле отбрасывает в разные места то есть плавного нет скрола как без события клик (если его не ставить)
я так понимаю проблема в OnTouchListener самого ImageView, если создать свою view от ImageView и переопределить метод вот так onTouchEvent

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
```

то скрол работает как надо но click не работает, как можно решить ? я получается в tableLayout добавляю 100 динамических ImageView и когда я ставлю событие клик я чувствую что система подвисает что ли, без клика все плавно работает но нужен клик, чтобы понять по какой картинке кликнули
как вообще такое решить можно ?
Спасибо

Comment: У Вас `TableLayout` завёрнут в `ScrollView` и `HorizontalScrollView`, которые сами реализуют прокрутку. Зачем Вам этот `onTouchEvent` вообще?

Comment: если не переопределить onTouchEvent  у Activity, то скрол только вертикально и горизонтально работает, но не работает если я хочу пальцем провести от центра до угла, я не знаю как это правильно объяснить то есть скрол только вертикально и горизонтально работает а наискосок не работает

Comment: А `onTouchEvent` суперкласса у потомка вызывать? Иначе же он "забывает" как на тачи реагировать.

Comment: если вызывать  return super.onTouchEvent(ev) у view от ImageView, то скрол ведет себя очень странно, например если я листаю вниз и отпускаю то он перекидывает меня на исходную позицию, откуда я и начал, то есть дергается. я и не знаю как это решить, может у вас есть какая нибудь библиотека для вертикального и горизонтального скрола и во все углы просто простой скрол он тупо по горизонтали и вертикали а мне ещё нужно например от центра в угол)) и такой скрол я сделал, но проблему с ImageView решить не могу если ставить событие на Imageview onClick